# Youtube api relatedToVideoId gives incorrect amount of videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I need to implement a custom autoplay feature for youtube iFrame, so I decided to use [youtube api relatedToVideoId feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId).

The problem is that for some reason often when you try to get only 1 related video it does not give any videos at all even though it says it has a lot of them in results.

Example request:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[YOUR_KEY]&maxResults=1&part=snippet&type=video&relatedToVideoId=DlFmfxACvig

Response:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/ShTuZSfQoay1YL6jgovx1wFiJSA\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
    "regionCode": "KG",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 553,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": []
}
```

As you can see there is no video in the `items` array, but it says that there are 553 `totalResults`. Also if you increase `maxResults` to 2 you will get 1 video instead.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the example request you provided in your question, I did make the following modifications:

- Increase the `maxResults` value to 2 or greater. For this case, I set the value to 5.
  According to the documentation, range of values are between 0 and 50.

This is the [Google API Explorer example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=5&relatedToVideoId=DlFmfxACvig&type=video&fields=items(id(kind%252CvideoId)%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Ctitle))%252CpageInfo%252CtokenPagination&_h=6&) with the `videoId` you provided - there, I set the request for bring specific fields.

With the modifications made, these are the results:

```
{
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 556,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "WlosjSe5B8c"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCtylTUUVIGY_i5afsQYeBZA",
    "title": "Lil Skies - Red Roses ft. Landon Cube (Dir. by @_ColeBennett_)",
    "channelTitle": "Lyrical Lemonade"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "4eS5o3beHko"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCtylTUUVIGY_i5afsQYeBZA",
    "title": "Lil Skies - Creeping ft. Rich The Kid (Dir. by @_ColeBennett_)",
    "channelTitle": "Lyrical Lemonade"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "mzB1VGEGcSU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCtylTUUVIGY_i5afsQYeBZA",
    "title": "Juice WRLD - Lucid Dreams (Dir. by @_ColeBennett_)",
    "channelTitle": "Lyrical Lemonade"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "kxloC1MKTpg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCrFB54bqp8sda4udJyNswlA",
    "title": "DJ Khaled - No Brainer (Official Video) ft. Justin Bieber, Chance the Rapper, Quavo",
    "channelTitle": "DJKhaledVEVO"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Despite the response shows `pageInfo.totalResults` are 556, YouTube has its own thresholds, so, I wouldn't trust getting these quantity of data in the same response. The limit I beleive is set to 50.